# Any JS based image gallery that I can integrate with my Web Application?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a web app integrated with CKEDITOR . The image plugin is supposed to open a web browser that has image gallery which the user can select . I can simply sent the URL of the images from the server along with a HTML content or a JS file . I prefer to sent a JS file name that actually has the logic to present a simple image gallery which the user can use .
Can anyone tell me some good solutions for this .